# Running multiple python scripts in one Azure Function

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

As the title says I want to have an Azure function that runs all of the Python scripts in that project. My ideal state would look something like this.

```
-azure_app
  - azure_function
    - __init__.py (runs code)
    - function.json (trigger)
    - python_script_one.py
    - python_script_two.py
```

The Python scripts I have are running crawlers for different websites and require different processes. However, they are part of the same project so in an ideal world, I would have all of the individual Python files and have the init file call all of them in one function so that I don't have to generate a multitude of different functions for each script. I've struggled to find a solution to this so any advice is much appreciated.

I am using a timer as the trigger for the function the code is as follows.

```
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Running multiple python scripts in one Azure Function

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Firstly, created azure python http trigger function and then created 2 files  as below:

**`p1.py:`**

```
print("Hello Rithwik running from Script 1")
```

[image]

**`p2.py:`**

```
print("Running from Script 2")
```

[image]

Then in **`__init__.py`**:

```
import logging

from pkg_resources import run_script
import azure.functions as func
import sys
import os
import importlib.util


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    rs('p1')
    rs('p2')
    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
def rs(sn):
    sp = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f'{sn}.py')

    s = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(sn, sp)
    m = importlib.util.module_from_spec(s)
    sys.modules[s.name] = m
    s.loader.exec_module(m)
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for the help. I am using a timer as the trigger function for the init file. It seems like the 'rs' function is the same. Do you have advice on how  I should I adapt it? I added the timer function code.

Comment: Yes , rs function is same, just add ```rs('p1')
    rs('p2')``` these two lines of code in the timer trigger function, just add them inside the function and it will execute, p1 and p2 are names of scripts

Comment: @RithwikBojja how to ensure that it's executed on the first instance.