# Running background scheduled tasks (Python) on Azure WebApp

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Web App that is currently running on a Linux environment. I have a Python script that needs to run in the background every 4 hours. This script uses external modules such as pysftp, pandas, among others. It's important to note that this script is not an API; it's a data transformation script that runs entirely on the backend. How can I set up the execution of this script in the background every 4 hours?

I've tried using the Python schedule module and also crontab, since we are dealing with a Linux system, but so far, I haven't achieved successful results in either case

Answer (score 0):

I use below timer trigger azure function which calls a script like below and followed this [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76411892/17623802):

```
import datetime
import logging
from pkg_resources import run_script
import sys
import os
import importlib.util as iu
import azure.functions as func


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    rithwik_script('test')
    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
def rithwik_script(run_script):
    spath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f'{run_script}.py')
    s = iu.spec_from_file_location(run_script, spath)
    m = iu.module_from_spec(s)
    sys.modules[s.name] = m
    s.loader.exec_module(m)
```

script to be executed(test.py):

```
print("Hello Rithwik Bojja")
```

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

You can add the packages in requirements.txt file:

[image]